# join 3 table in mysql with non relation table

Tags: mysql, database

hello folks i have 3 table table a,table b, table c

**table a**

```
id  | name   
 1  | agent1 
 2  | agent2
```

**table b**

```
id  | action   
 1  | product 
 2  | saving
 3  | transfer
 4  | sell
```

**table c**

```
 id | table_a | table_b | status | delay(sec)
  1 |  1      | 1       | 2      | 10
  2 |  1      | 2       | 2      | 5
```

expected output

```
name    | action  | count  |avg(delay)
 agent1 | product | 1      | 10
 agent1 | saving  | 1      | 5
 agent1 | transfer| 0      | 0
 agent1 | sell    | 0      | 0
 agent2 | product | 0      | 0
 agent2 | saving  | 0      | 0
 agent2 | transfer| 0      | 0
 agent2 | sell    | 0      | 0
```

Can anyone tell me how I can achieve expected output since my sql not support `outer join` so I got confused ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following solution using a `INNER JOIN` on `tableA` and `tableB` without condition and a `LEFT JOIN` on `tableC`:

```
SELECT tableA.name, tableB.action, COUNT(tableC.id) AS `count`, AVG(delay) AS delay
FROM (tableA, tableB) LEFT JOIN tableC ON tableA.id = tableC.table_a AND tableB.id = tableC.table_b
GROUP BY tableA.name, tableB.action
ORDER BY tableA.name, tableB.action
```

> [**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a2df1fea9cf416a5f916a96fac673a65)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.name, b.action , COUNT(c.id) as count , AVG(delay) 
FROM test.table_a a CROSS JOIN test.table_b b 
LEFT JOIN test.table_c c
ON c.table_a = a.id AND c.table_b = b.id
GROUP BY a.id ,b.id
ORDER BY a.id,b.id;
```